# Java/Joda: Get TimeZone from long name (Display Name)

Tags: java, datetime, formatting, timezone, icalendar

In receiving iCal events from Outlook, it is specifying the timezone in the long format:

```
DTSTART;TZID=Eastern Standard Time:20120521T180000
```

That is, what you'd get from TimeZone.getDisplayName().

How can I go from that (`Eastern Standard Time`) to a TimeZone object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it ain't pretty, but here's what I ended up with (basically, iterate over available TZ's, searching for a `getDisplayName()` match):

// NOTE: vTZID is the timezone ID as presented by the iCalendar format
// For example 'Eastern Standard Time'.  I only do this if the TZ cannot be found by the normal method
// (that is, TimeZone.getTimeZone())

```
boolean foundTZ=false;
for (String availId : TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()){
  if (vTZID.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(TimeZone.getTimeZone(availId).getDisplayName())){
    vTimezone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(availId);
    foundTZ = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at olson time zone ? also available in joda: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html

Comment: Unfortunately, the olson db as implemented neither Java nor Joda will lookup based on the long format name.